# Deploy a Flex project in a remote webserver

Tags: apache-flex, deployment

I have coded my Flex / PHP project in a local machine. I have used AMFphp for remoting and I got to deploy and test this application in a remote server. How could I do this using Flashbuilder 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

Export a release build. This will export an optimized swf

Then, copy the bin-release folder (depends on your project configuration) as-is to the server.

Of course, you'll have to make sure that your server is configured for AMFPHP. Though I haven't used this myself, I have used ColdFusion-Flex remoting and I know there needs to be a /flex2gateway/ path and other such stuff configured on the server for that. I believe most hosting service providers have this already done, so in the unlikely case it isn't (you'll get an error in Flash Player or the app won't work as expected) you just need to tell your server support to do it for you (If you can't, then that would be another question on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)